# Error into app using MaterialNavigationDrawer with ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that uses MaterialNavigationDrawer as left side menu, and it has 6 options (in vertical order) that can be opened in this menu: 5 options opens fragments (Headlines, Trends, Interests, Notifications, Settings) and 1 opens dialog (Logout).

The options "Trends", "Interests", "Notifications" and "Settings" simply opens a colored fragment. The option "Headlines" opens a ViewPager that can have until 31 tabs generated dinamically. The class that manages this "Headlines" option is the class HeadlinesFragment.

The MaterialNavigationDrawer is set into TimelineActivity, that calls the 6 menu options: HeadlinesFragment, TendenciesFragment, InterestsFragment, NotificationsFragment, SettingsFragment or LogoutDialog.

The class HeadlinesFragment has the ViewPager, set into the class HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter. And this class calls dinamic instances of the class HeadlinesPagerFragment. So we have this logic:

TimelineActivity -> HeadlinesFragment -> HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter -> HeadlinePagerFragment

- TimelineActivity: class that instances the MaterialNavigationDrawer.
- HeadlinesFragment: first menu option of MaterialNavigationDrawer.
- HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter: view pager adapter where we put each tab (can be 31 in total).
- HeadlinePagerFragment: the fragment related to the tab of the ViewPager.

The problem I'm facing in this app is: when I choose an option like Trends, Interests, Notifications or Settings (which just opens a simple colored fragment), and then I return for the Headline option, the app crashes.

Below I show the source code of the 4 classes described above.

**TimelineActivity**

```
public class TimelineActivity extends MaterialNavigationDrawer {

    // ATTRIBUTES

    // Context.
    private Activity mActivity = TimelineActivity.this;

    // Material Navigation Drawer.
    private MaterialSection[] mSectionArray = new MaterialSection[NavigationDrawerOptions.values().length];
    private int[] mSectionColors = new int[NavigationDrawerOptions.values().length];

    // MATERIAL NAVIGATION DRAWER

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "TimelineActivity.init().");
        ColorUtils.changeStatusBarTransparent(getWindow());
        setSections();
    }

    // METHODS

    private void setSections() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "TimelineActivity.setSections().");
        String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_list__navigation_drawer);
        setSectionColors();

        // Sets sections.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        int imageId = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NavigationDrawerOptions.values().length; i++) {
            NavigationDrawerOptions option = NavigationDrawerOptions.fromInt(i);
            switch (option) {
                case HEADLINES:
                    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "TimelineActivity.setSections() -> HEADLINES.");
                    fragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
                    imageId = R.mipmap.ic_headlines_off;
                    break;
                case TRENDS:
                    fragment = new TendenciesFragment();
                    imageId = R.mipmap.ic_trends_off;
                    break;
                case INTERESTS:
                    fragment = new InterestsFragment();
                    imageId = R.mipmap.ic_interests_off;
                    break;
                case NOTIFICATIONS:
                    fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                    imageId = R.mipmap.ic_notifications_off;
                    break;
                case SETTINGS:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    imageId = R.mipmap.ic_settings;
                    break;
                case LOGOUT:
                    mSectionArray[i] = newSection(titles[i], R.mipmap.ic_logout, new MaterialSectionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(MaterialSection section) {
                            LogoutDialog dialog = new LogoutDialog(mActivity);
                            Utils.callBackgroundDialog(mActivity, dialog);
                        }
                    });
                    addSection(mSectionArray[i]);
                    break;
            }

            if (option != NavigationDrawerOptions.LOGOUT) {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "TimelineActivity.setSections() -> addSection().");
                mSectionArray[i] = newSection(titles[i], imageId, fragment);
                addSection(mSectionArray[i]);
                mSectionArray[i].setSectionColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mSectionColors[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    private void setSectionColors() {
        mSectionColors[0] = Globals.HEADLINES_THEME_COLOR;
        mSectionColors[1] = Globals.TRENDS_THEME_COLOR;
        mSectionColors[2] = Globals.INTERESTS_THEME_COLOR;
        mSectionColors[3] = Globals.NOTIFICATIONS_THEME_COLOR;
        mSectionColors[4] = Globals.SETTINGS_THEME_COLOR;
        mSectionColors[5] = Globals.LOGOUT_THEME_COLOR;
    }
}
```

**HeadlinesFragment**

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends BaseFragment {

    // ATTRIBUTES

    // Context.
    private Activity mActivity;

    // Layout.
    private ImageView mParentView;
    private View mRootView;

    private List<Interest> mInterestList;

    private HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter mHeadlinesViewPagerAdapter;
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public static HeadlinesFragment newInstance() {
        HeadlinesFragment fragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    // FRAGMENT LIFE CYCLE

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.onCreateView().");
        mActivity = getActivity();

        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines, container, false);

        ColorUtils.changeStatusBarTransparent(getActivity().getWindow());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setLayout();

        return mRootView;
    }

    // VIEW METHODS

    private void setLayout() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setLayout().");
        mInterestList = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests();

        mParentView = (ImageView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines__parent_view);

        hideBottomView();
        setViewPager();
    }

    private void hideBottomView() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.hideBottomView().");
        Utils.hideBottomView(mRootView, R.id.id_fragment_headlines__main_linear_layout, KitKatEnum.LINEAR_LAYOUT_OPTION);
        Utils.hideBottomView(mRootView, R.id.id_fragment_headlines__bottom_image_view, KitKatEnum.IMAGE_VIEW_OPTION);
    }

    private void setViewPager() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setViewPager().");
        setViewPagerAdapter();
        setViewPagerListeners();
    }

    private void setViewPagerAdapter() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setViewPagerAdapter().");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines__view_pager);

        mHeadlinesViewPagerAdapter = new HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), mInterestList);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mHeadlinesViewPagerAdapter);

        onPageSelectedAction(0);
        setTabs();
    }

    private void setViewPagerListeners() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setViewPagerListeners().");
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setViewPagerListeners().onPageSelected().");
                onPageSelectedAction(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
    }

    private void onPageSelectedAction(Integer position) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.onPageSelectedAction(" + position + ").");
        // Gets colors.
        updatesCurrentThemeColor(position);
        String color = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(position).getColor();
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.onPageSelectedAction().onPageSelectedAction(" + position + ") -> " +
            "Current theme color is " + color + ".");

        // Changes colors.
        String alphaColor = ColorUtils.addTransparencyToColor(color);
        int colorId = Color.parseColor(alphaColor);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.circle_button);
        drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));

        // Updates Headline list.
        HeadlinesPagerFragment fragment = (HeadlinesPagerFragment)(
                (HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(position);
        if (fragment != null) {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.onPageSelectedAction().onPageSelectedAction(" + position + ") -> " +
                "Calling getHeadlineList().");
            getHeadlineList(fragment);
        }
    }

    private void updatesCurrentThemeColor(Integer position) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setPageNumber(position);
        User loggedUser = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser();
        String color = loggedUser.getInterests().get(position).getColor();
        ContentManager.getInstance().setCurrentThemeColor(color);
    }

    private void setTabs() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.setTabs().");
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines__sliding_tab_layout);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);

        mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager for the SlidingTabsLayout.
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    // HEADLINE METHODS

    private void getHeadlineList(HeadlinesPagerFragment fragment) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.getHeadlineList().");
        // Variables.
        Integer pageNumber = ContentManager.getInstance().getPageNumber();
        Integer interestId = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(pageNumber).getId();
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.getHeadlineList() -> Page number is " + pageNumber + ".");
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.getHeadlineList() -> Interest id is " + interestId + ".");

        // Retrofit.
        String pagination = "10,0";
        String sort = "desc";
        String filters;
        if (interestId == 0) {
            filters = "popularity:+popular";
        } else {
            filters = "category:" + interestId + "|type:posts";
        }

        // Checks connection.
        if (!Utils.hasConnection(mActivity)) {
            Utils.callLostConnectionDialog(mActivity);
        } else {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesFragment.getHeadlineList() -> Calling RetrofitUtils.searchMake().");
            String[] fields = new String[] { pagination, sort, filters };
            RetrofitUtils.searchMake(mActivity, fragment, null, fields,
                SearchMakeEnum.HEADLINES_PAGER_FRAGMENT, Utils.hourglass(mActivity));
        }
    }
}
```

**HeadlinesViewPagerFragment**

```
public class HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    // ATTRIBUTES

    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    private List<Interest> mInterestsList;
    private List<HeadlinesPagerFragment> mFragments;

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public HeadlinesViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Interest> interestList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mInterestsList = interestList;

        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<>();
        mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mInterestsList.size(); i++) {
            mFragments.add(HeadlinesPagerFragment.create(i));
        }
    }

    // FRAGMENT PAGER ADAPTER METHODS

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mInterestsList.get(position).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mInterestsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (object instanceof Fragment) {
            // Record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
            String tag = fragment.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return object;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

**HeadlinesPagerFragment**

```
public class HeadlinesPagerFragment extends BaseFragment {

    // CONSTANTS
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    // ATTRIBUTES

    // Context.
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    // Recycler view.
    private ViewGroup mRootView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private HeadlineAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Headline> mHeadlineList;

    // Others.
    private TextView mEmptyTextView;

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public static HeadlinesPagerFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        HeadlinesPagerFragment fragment = new HeadlinesPagerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    // FRAGMENT LIFE CYCLE

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.onCreateView().");
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mFragment = this;

        mRootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines_pager, container, false);
        setLayout();
        return mRootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.onResume() -> At onResume().");
        // Updates Headline list.
        updateHeadlinesList();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Integer number = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, getString(R.string.big_space));
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setUserVisibleHint() -> Current position is " + number + ".");
            ContentManager.getInstance().setPageNumber(number);

            String color = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(number).getColor();
            ContentManager.getInstance().setCurrentThemeColor(color);
        }
    }

    // LAYOUT METHODS

    private void setLayout() {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setLayout().");
        // Sets the layout.
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__swipe_refresh_layout);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__recycler_view);
        mEmptyTextView = (TextView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__empty_text_view);
        Typeface fontType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), Globals.FONT_TYPE);
        mEmptyTextView.setTypeface(fontType);
    }

    private void setRecyclerView(CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setRecyclerView().");
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setRecyclerView() -> Headline list size is " + mHeadlineList.size() + ".");
        Integer pageNumber = ContentManager.getInstance().getPageNumber();
        List<Interest> interestsList = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests();
        Integer categoryId = interestsList.get(pageNumber).getId();
        mAdapter = new HeadlineAdapter(getActivity(), this, categoryId, null, mHeadlineList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

    // HEADLINE METHODS

    private void updateHeadlinesList() {
        // Variables.
        Integer pageNumber = ContentManager.getInstance().getPageNumber();
        Integer interestId = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(pageNumber).getId();
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> Page number is " + pageNumber + ".");
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> Interest id is " + interestId + ".");

        // Retrofit.
        String pagination = "10,0";
        String sort = "desc";
        String filters;
        if (interestId == 0) {
            filters = "popularity:+popular";
        } else {
            filters = "category:" + interestId + "|type:posts";
        }

        // Checks connection.
        if (!Utils.hasConnection(mActivity)) {
            Utils.callLostConnectionDialog(mActivity);
        } else {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> Calling RetrofitUtils.searchMake().");
            String[] fields = new String[] { pagination, sort, filters };
            RetrofitUtils.searchMake(mActivity, mFragment, null, fields,
                SearchMakeEnum.HEADLINES_PAGER_FRAGMENT, Utils.hourglass(mActivity));
        }
    }

    // CALLBACK

    public void checkValidHeadlineList(Boolean append, CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList().");
        List<Post> postList = ContentManager.getInstance().getPostList();
        mHeadlineList = RecyclerViewUtils.getHeadlineListFromPostList(postList);
        if (append) {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Append list.");
            mAdapter.setFilter(mHeadlineList);
            progressDialog.cancel();
        } else {
            Boolean validHeadlineList = (mHeadlineList != null) && (mHeadlineList.size() > 0);
            if (validHeadlineList) {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Valid list.");
                mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setRecyclerView(progressDialog);
            } else {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Empty list.");
                mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the LogCat of error:

```
05-14 00:36:40.742 30234-30234/com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine, PID: 30234
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.fragment.HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList(HeadlinesPagerFragment.java:172)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.json.JsonPostRawUtils.choosePostList(JsonPostRawUtils.java:98)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.json.JsonPostRawUtils.parsePostSearchData(JsonPostRawUtils.java:73)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.retrofit.RetrofitUtils.searchMakeOnSuccess(RetrofitUtils.java:232)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.retrofit.RetrofitUtils.access$100(RetrofitUtils.java:38)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.retrofit.RetrofitUtils$5.success(RetrofitUtils.java:213)
at com.example.rodrigo.facemagazine.manager.utils.retrofit.RetrofitUtils$5.success(RetrofitUtils.java:199)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The line 172 of HeadlinesPagerFragment is the highlighted line below:

```
public void checkValidHeadlineList(Boolean append, CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList().");
    List<Post> postList = ContentManager.getInstance().getPostList();
    mHeadlineList = RecyclerViewUtils.getHeadlineListFromPostList(postList);
    if (append) {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Append list.");
        mAdapter.setFilter(mHeadlineList);
        progressDialog.cancel();
    } else {
        Boolean validHeadlineList = (mHeadlineList != null) && (mHeadlineList.size() > 0);
        if (validHeadlineList) {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Valid list.");
            // <<<<<--------------- ERROR IN THE LINE BELOW --------------->>>>>
            mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setRecyclerView(progressDialog);
        } else {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Empty list.");
            mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- check void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)
- you use mEmptyTextView please check XML and Java Code ..
- in XML from     Where you declare     mEmptyTextView
- right :-android:visibility="gone"
- Wrong:- android:visibility="10"(any number)

In Java use

- right is:-        mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
- Wrong is:-  mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(10);it gives error you
  cannot run the code woth this line

  Please check it and post the error again

Comment: I solved this problem when I stopped using the MaterialNavigationDrawer, switching it for the NavigationView + DrawerLayout components.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some things in my code. I changed the tabs of the *ViewPager* from *SlidingTabLayout* to *TabLayout* from *'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'*, and the app stopped crashing.

So now I'm using the Google libs:

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

But now he is showing a white screen when I click into HeadlinesFragment.

This video shows this bug:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxDtTZOoM5A&feature=youtu.be

So, like I said in the first post:

1) *HeadlinesFragment* is called when the user clicks in the first option of the left side menu (which is a *MaterialNavigationDrawer*).

2) This fragment contains a *ViewPager* and a *TabLayout*. The *ViewPager* calls several instances of *HeadlinesPagerFragment*.

3) *HeadlinesPagerFragment* contains a *RecyclerView*. And here is where the bug happens: when I change an option from the left side menu, from "Manchetes" ("Headlines" in english) to some other like in the video ("Notificações", in english "Notifications"), the *HeadlinesFragment* re-opens the tabs, but some of them stay white, without loading the *RecyclerView*.

So here are the steps to reproduce the bug:

1) I log into the app.

2) I click into the first option of the left side menu ("Manchetes"), and then click in each tab of this option. The 4 tabs opens normally.

3) I choose other option of the left side menu (this time, "Notificações"). And the *NotificationsFragment* is called, bringing all the notifications of the user. Ok.

4) I choose other option of the left side menu. This time, the option "Manchetes" (at 0:20 of the video). This option opens the first tab "Destaques" ("Highlights" in English), and loads the data from server. But at 0:25 I click into the 3rd tab "Casa e Decoração" ("House and Decoration" in English), and that's the bug! The *RecyclerView* is not shown. A white screen appears into this tab.

If I check into the log, all the data from Backend is ok. The data is passing for the *HeadlineAdapter* (the adapter of the *RecyclerView* from *HeadlinesFragment*), but, the tab stays white.

I don't know why this is happening. Whats is the reason?

1) Bug into *MaterialNavigationDrawer*? It is very possible, because this bug just happens when I switch from left side menu options.

2) Bug into *ViewPager*?

3) Bug into *RecyclerView* or it adapter?

4) Some synchronization problem?

Well, after I post this question, I will try to replace the left side menu of my app, from *MaterialNavigationDrawer* to *DrawerLayout* with *NavigationView*, to see what happens.

Comment: I solved this problem when I stopped using the MaterialNavigationDrawer, switching it for the NavigationView + DrawerLayout components.